# How to make class generic to pass dynamic property class in c#

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have demo code which ignores the `Extra` property. I need to make this class generic.

```
public class HelloFriend 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new StringBuilder();
        s.Append("Id,Name\r\n");
        s.Append("1,one\r\n");
        s.Append("2,two\r\n");
        using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TestMap>();
            csv.GetRecords<Test>().ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class Test : Test1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Test1
{
    public decimal Extra { get; set; }
}

public class TestMap : CsvClassMap<Test>
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        AutoMap();
        Map(m => m.Extra).Ignore();
    }
}
```

As shown in above code if I need to use different `Test1`, or `Test2` instead of Test, then I need to write another `TestMap` class. How can I avoid this? How can I make this class generic, so I can pass multiple classes like `Test` to ignore the `Extra` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean somehting like this?

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new StringBuilder();
        s.Append("Id,Name\r\n");
        s.Append("1,one\r\n");
        s.Append("2,two\r\n");
        using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TestMap<Test>>();
            csv.GetRecords<Test>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
public class Test : Test1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public Abstract class Test1 
{
   public decimal Extra { get; set; }
}


public class Test2 : Test1
{
    //other propertys
}


public class TestMap<T> : CsvClassMap<T> where T : Test1
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        AutoMap();

            Map(m => m.Extra).Ignore();

    }
}
```

Comment: yes some thing like this but in TestMap class i wan to avoid that 2 times declaration for Test1 and Test 2 , it must be generic so we can pass any class for ignoring that property

Comment: @Tiger is it always the same property ("Extra") ?

Comment: ok I update my anwser. I am not sure if this is realy what you mean. Now every class which inhiert from Test ignore this "Extra" Property.

Comment: the below code works .'public class TestMap<T> : CsvClassMap<T> where T : Test1 
    {
        public TestMap()
        {
            AutoMap();
            Map(m => m.Extra).Ignore(); 
        }
    }'

Comment: Thanks @Darem i got the idea from your answer

Comment: Nice to hear that i can help:)

Answer (score 1):

```
class CsvClassMap<T> where T:Test1,class 
{
    //your class logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it might work and help you for a while as long as you do not add more properties or your class interface stays stable.

Besides, i'd suggest to reinforce your implementation by adding custom attribute and using reflection to detect which properties to ignore. Here is some code to give you an idea:

```
public class ToBeIgnoredAttribute:Attribute
{

}

public class Test
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }

    [ToBeIgnored]
    public int Property2 { get; set; }

}
var type= typeof(Test)// or typeof(T);
type.GetProperties().ForEach(prop =>
{

            if (prop.GetCustomAttribute<ToBeIgnoredAttribute>() != null)
            {
              Console.WriteLine($"//Call Map with right overload e.g with property name string {prop.Name}"); 
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name} is not ignored");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `AutoMap`, only map the properties you want to be mapped.

```
public class TestMap : ClassMap<Test>
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Name);
    }
}
```

Another option is to add an attribute to the property.

```
public abstract class Test1
{
    [Ignore]
    public decimal Extra { get; set; }
}

public class TestMap : ClassMap<Test>
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        AutoMap();
    }
}
```